# Is there a way to speed up the pandas getitem, getitem_axis and get_label?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have the loop below and I can't use `assign` or vectorize it because I am modifying several objects and functions further down the line. However, the pandas selections are taking the bulk of the execution time. Is there a way to circumvent this?

```
if date in data[instrument].index:   
    row = data[instrument].ix[date]
```

- nb calls   tottime    percall     cumtime
- 34124    0.04444       1.302e-06 7.085   0.0002076   indexing.py:108(_getitem)
- 34124    0.08395 2.46e-06    7.029   0.000206 indexing.py:1044(_getitem_axis)
- 34124    0.0316  9.26e-07    6.242   0.0001829   indexing.py:123(_get_label)
- 34124    0.258    7.56e-06   6.207   0.0001819   generic.py:1827(xs)

**Edit**: It turns out that `dict.__getitem__` is much faster than the above methods with pandas. Therefore, I can convert everything with something like this:

```
dict[(date, instrument)] = pd.Series.to_dict(data[instrument].ix[date]).
```

I only need to set it once and the rest of the code that i will reuse several times is now around 54 times faster.